# Is it legal to share links to file hosting sites containing copyrighted material?

Tags: copyright

I was wondering if there are any illegal aspects about sharing a link to a file hosting site (e.g. mega/dropbox) to download copyrighted material such as movies etc.

Are there any differences if I just share the link compared to if I also upload files on a site and then share it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it infringement to give a link to a copyrighted file?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4360/is-it-infringement-to-give-a-link-to-a-copyrighted-file)

Comment: "if I also upload files on a site" - If you upload copyrighted files to a site without permission then yes this is infringement, whether you then link to them or not. There might be some exceptions to this if you are doing this only to make a personal backup of your files and not using it to make it available to others, but that doesn't sound like the situation here.

Comment: @Brandin Im intending to make a public collection of those links. Is that also infringement if I don't upload them? Just sharing links basicaly.

Comment: The answer(s) are in the other question I linked to.

Comment: Hello Marc Kohler!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page, linked at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it infringement to give a link to a copyrighted file?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4360/is-it-infringement-to-give-a-link-to-a-copyrighted-file)